# Delete single linked list recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

It looks there is no duplicate questions...so i want a function to free all nodes in a single linked list, and i want to do it recursively. I come up with a close one that i thought it would work, but it does not. It seems that after it removed one node, the upper stack function will not excuse, recursively. I am wondering how to modify the code to make it work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node 
{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
};

void ft_list_clear(struct Node *begin_list)
{
    if ((begin_list->next))
      ft_list_clear(begin_list->next);
    if(!(begin_list->next))
    {
      free(begin_list);
      begin_list = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  struct Node* second = NULL;
  struct Node* third = NULL;

  // allocate 3 nodes in the heap  
  head  = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  third  = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  head->data = 1; //assign data in first node
  head->next = second; // Link first node with second   

  second->data = 2; //assign data to second node
  second->next = third;  

  third->data = 3; //assign data to third node
  third->next = NULL;

  ft_list_clear(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete linked list using recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342105/delete-linked-list-using-recursive-function) It is in C++ but should be fairly trivial to port to C.

Comment: Note that creating 10,000 stack frames to delete a medium-sized linked list is a really bad idea.

Comment: totally. the iterative method is straight-forward and efficient. I just come this to mind and wish to have it work. Thanks for pointing that out @DaveS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're just freeing nodes, but you miss to nullify the `next` members. Try this. I haven't run this so goodluck.

```
void ft_list_clear(struct Node *begin_list)
{
    if ((begin_list->next))
    {
      ft_list_clear(begin_list->next);
      begin_list->next = NULL; // <-- you should nullify the next of the current after you free the node which it points to.
    }
    if(!(begin_list->next)) // <-- even if the next node was deleted, this won't run if you didn't nullify begin_list->next
    {
      free(begin_list);
      begin_list = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: i see. so even if the next node was freed, the next pointer still points to the 'address' rather than NULL?

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close

```
void ft_list_clear(struct Nude *list)
{
   if (!list) { return; }

   ft_list_clear(list->next);
   list->next = null;
   free(list);
}
```

Explaining the code

The first `if` checks if the list is currently `null` and exits the recursion if so.

If the list isn't `null` recursively call the function.
This repeats until the end of the list `null`.
Then since the `next` has been cleared by the recursive call you can set it to `null` in this call (not strictly necessary since this clears everything). 
Finally actually `free` this node prior to returning to the previous call (this node's parent).

You can also do the delete in the opposite order if you want

```
void ft_list_clear(string Node *list)
{
   if (!list) { return; }
   struct Node *next = list->next;
   free(list);
   ft_list_clear(next);
}
```

Same principles just deletes this node before going to the next. This means you don't need to fix the `next` pointers but you will need to copy them first so you don't lose the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explaination! Your code is so powerful that we do not even need list->next = null; line.

Comment: yeah i know it's effectively a NOOP but sometimes it's helpful just to keep track of what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

`void ft_list_clear(struct Node *begin_list)

```
{
    if ((begin_list->next))
      ft_list_clear(begin_list->next);

    free(begin_list);
    begin_list = NULL;
    printf("God bless America");
}`
```

Hopefully, if God blesses America thrice, your code is working, I've committed some changes in your code, and all I did was remove the second if statement because usually, we don't need that in recursion (I'm not saying we don't need more than one if statement). Test it yourself and you'll understand why it's so. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this

```
void ft_list_clear(struct Node *begin_list)
{
    if ((begin_list->next))
      ft_list_clear(begin_list->next);
    if(!(begin_list->next))
    {
      free(begin_list);
      begin_list = NULL;
    }
}
```

is:

- In the first call, `begin_list` is equal to `head`.
- `head->next` is not `NULL`, so `ft_list_clear(second)` is executed
- `second->next` is not `NULL`, so `ft_list_clear(third)` is executed
- `third->next` is `NULL`, so `free(third)` happens. The `begin_list = NULL`
  line does nothing here, its pointless.
- The third iteration returns, back to the second. The next line to execute is

  ```
  if(!(begin_list->next))
  ```

  `begin_list->next` is **not** NULL (it's been only `free`d), hence the condition is evaluated to `false` and the `free`
  is not executed.
- Same happens with the first iteration.

This is recursion that would work:

```
void ft_list_clear(struct Node *begin_list)
{
    if(begin_list == NULL)
        return;

    ft_list_clear(begin_list->next);
    free(begin_list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively deleting a linked is a ***bad idea***. Each recursive call requires a stack frame, and whether you free the list node memory as you descend or ascend the recursion, you need O(n) memory for what is a simple operation. Each stack call requires local variable storage, room for return pointer, previous stack frame pointer, and possibly other stuff (at least 12-24 bytes per node).

Better to iterate through the list.  I have provided three variants of the free (iterative, and two recursive, one free's node on descent, one free's node on ascent).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} node_t;

long list_clear_iter(node_t* p) {
    if(!p) return 0;
    long n = 0; //count;
    for( ; p->next; ) {
        node_t* fp = p; //free this
        p = p->next;
        free(fp);
        ++n;
    }
    return n;
}

//list clear, recursive, (pre)free
long ft_list_clear_pr(node_t* p) {
    if(!p) return 0;
    node_t* np = p->next;
    free(p); //free on descend
    long n = ft_list_clear_pr(np);
    return(n+1);
}
//list clear recursive, free(post)
long ft_list_clear_rp(node_t* p) {
    if(!p) return 0;
    long n = ft_list_clear_rp(p->next);
    free(p); //free on ascend
    return(n+1);
}
```